# Anonynous struct + compound literal results in lint error

Tags: c, struct, anonymous-types, lint, compound-literals

I have a multiple structs (modeled after the types of definitions used by the microchip compiler, although this is not a microchip application) in my embedded, C99 compatible program .  Here is a typical example:

```
typedef struct
{
  union
  {
    struct
    {
      CommandDirection_t ReadWrite  : 1;
      RegisterAddress_t Register    : 7;
    };
    uint8_t Byte;
  };
} MemsAccelCommand_t;
```

CommandDirection_t and RigisterAddress_t are enums.  Later in my code I declare and initialize my struct:

```
MemsAccelCommand_t command = { .ReadWrite = CMD_Read };
```

This compiles with no warnings or errors, however when I lint the file, I get the error: "Error 65: Expected a member name".

How can I tweak my code so that the lint error is no longer raised, or what can I do to disable a lint warning for this (aside from disabling error 65)?

Comment: Have you ever solved this?

Comment: @ArnoMoonen Nope.  I haven't tested but you might be able to wrap the declaration with `-save -e65` and `-restore` to suppress it with minimal unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Give the union and the innermost structure a name, as in:

```
typedef struct
{
  union
  {
    struct
    {
      CommandDirection_t ReadWrite  : 1;
      RegisterAddress_t Register    : 7;
    } Byte_struct;
    uint8_t Byte;
  } Byte_union;
} MemsAccelCommand_t;
```

Otherwise, how do you plan to access the union fields? The union must have a name.

Comment: giving the anonymous struct and union a name causes compile errors that prevent me from using compound literal initialization: MemsAccelCommand_t ma = { .ReadWrite = CD_Read, .Register = RA_Ctrl1 }; --> The compiler can't identify the member names if the anonyomous types are not anonymous